# How to set up videojs for http Pseudo-streaming with nginx?

Tags: nginx, video-streaming, video.js

I am running a nginx webserver to deliver large static video files.
I set up the [mp4 module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mp4_module.html) as follow:

```
location /stream-files { 
    mp4; 
    mp4_buffer_size       1m; 
    mp4_max_buffer_size   5m; 
    alias /vagrant/shared/e-media/web/e-media-data/; 
}
```

I can now pass a start and stop get parameter in the url to read the video by chunk. 
I would like to configure my videojs player to use this feature in order.

How can I do that? Is that a correct way to stream large video files?

Answer (score 0):

This MP4 modules is not required at all for html5 video. Just host the MP4 like any other file and set the  to the url.